# Rendering objects in between third person camera and player

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm a student on a project and I'm stuck on a part of it. My project is to make a scene graph as well as a third person camera to move around, and have some gameplay.

What I'm stuck on, is the rendering. Since this is a third person camera, there is a distance between the camera and me. Now when a wall, or any object, come between the camera and me, it blocks my view.

My teacher mentioned that there are two ways to solve this: One to make the camera rise up, two to "not" render the wall.

My question is how do I detect that wall and not render it? When I run my render code in the scene graph, it would render everything. Should I be instead using a bool to control whether I want to render each node?

My gameplay revolves around being placed in a maze, so lifting the camera up isn't the most ideal result.

What I need is some psuedo-code and ideas to do this without messing around with the scene graph too much.

If there is a duplicate of this question, please point me to it, as I do not know what its called and cannot find it.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just draw the front face. Checkout https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling for more details.

Comment: @dari If I were to use this method, I need to change all my vertices to be rendered clockwise / counterclockwise right? I just now tried calling the function, but I'm rendering a lot of cubes in the same way, and it left me with a lot of holes in the cubes.

Comment: Yes, all faces have to be ordered correctly.

Comment: You can use glDepthRange() with a small non-zero nearVal, so OpenGL will cut your 3D scene right behind your character back, but if you make it too big, it will also cut your character. But that's a hack, I suggest to use face culling, and to fix your rendering code instead.
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDepthRange.xml

Comment: @dari The fact that the walls are 3D won't really matter right?